# Insert a character (".") before a span tag inside an h1 tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, insert

I'm working on a Help project that contains thousands of .htm topics. Each topic has a heading (inside a h1 tag). Each heading contains a span tag. I'm looking for a script that would allow me to insert a period (".") separator before the span tag in every h1 tag across all topics.

For example, I need to change...

```
<h1>Heading<span>Heading</span></h1>
```

to...

```
<h1>Heading.<span>Heading</span></h1>
```

I've tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work. (Note that I'm a relative newb when it comes to jquery/scripting.)

```
$(function(){
    $("h1.span").before(".");
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey @tddrchrdsn you can use "find()" as  $("h1").find("span").before(".") ...

Comment: `$("h1.span")` selects an `<h1>` element with the class "span". It seems you want to select `<span>` elements inside `<h1>` elements, e.g. `$("h1 span")`. For reference, see [jQuery Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: or just `$("h1 span").before(".");`. That space (and the dot) is where you went wrong: `h1 span` is the CSS selector for a `span` element inside an `h1`, as you want, whereas `h1.span` selects `h1` elements with a *class* of `span`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use CSS to add it using after and contents

```css
h1 span::after{
  content: "."
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Hello</span></h1>
<h1><span>World</span></h1>
<h1><span>Foo</span></h1>
<h1><span>Bar</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to query an element you've to find it with Jquery functions, I face you're confused with the "CSS" syntax, so you can use the "find()" Jquery function:

```
$("h1").find("span").before(".")
```

I hope it helps, regards.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```js
$("h1 span").prepend(".")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1><span>My brain</span> <span>Yo</span></h1>
<h1>Some test <span>Yo</span></h1>
<h1>Another test<span>Yo</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the following,

```
$('h1 > span').before('.');
```

This inserts a . before the span tag